# Excessive growth of Access 2010 database

Tags: database, ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2010

I have a problem of excessive database growth when inserting data via ODBC into an Access 2010 database (.accdb). For example, in one case the database grows from 24MB to 140MB, but when compacted shrinks back to ~24MB.

What I've noticed is that the database have tables with multiple text fields which are indexed. Can it be causing such excessive growth? Are there any other reasons for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the growth is most likely the fragmentation. It occurs when data is often deleted. I believe it is unrelated to the insertion. Had a similar problem with my database. I found that I unnecessarily inserted records just to show a certain dialog box, and deleted them straight away. It was a "shortcut" in the coding of a feature in a program. When I corrected the code (basically, I have modified the code to not delete the records, but just keep) the growth stopped. So, just check your Insertion procedure. If it deletes first (to avoid duplicates or outdated data), then change this code to UPDATE existing records.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. You are right, before insertion the old data is deleted from the database. That's also the reason why the database shrinks to the original size after compaction.

Comment: Your version of Access also has a feature to automatically do a compact-repair every time you close the DB. Go to File - Options - Current Database, then check the box that says 'Compact on Close'.